# Проверка на сортировку

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с числами, нужно проверить есть ли в массиве элемент, удалив который массив будет отсортирован по возростанию.(убрать можно только одно число, в любых других случаях должен быть false)
На пример: [1,3,2] если убрать 3, то массив будет по возростанию.
Есть 4 варианта для которых код должен быть правильным:

[1,3,2]-true

[2,4,2,1]-false

[5,5,5,5,5]-false

[5,6,7]-true

мой код:

```js
function solution(x){
return x.sort((a,b)=>a-b)?true:false
  for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
   if(x.splice(i)===x.sort((a,b)=>a-b)){
    return true
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: было недавно уже

Comment: идите по массиву. если последующее больше предыдущего максимума. то запоминаете максимум. если меньше, то запомните это и идите дальше. Если второй раз встретилось число меньше максимума то на выход.

Comment: да уж, недавно. год прошел. не смог даже свой ответ найти. но похоже новый ответ будет покрасивше тех :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вариация на тему

```js
function check(v){    
    
    return 1 >= v.reduce((acc, c) => (c > acc.m ? acc.m = c  : acc.x++, acc), 
                   { m: Number.MIN_VALUE, x:0 }
                ).x;
}


const data = [
      [1,3,2],
      [2,4,2,1],
      [5,5,5,5,5],
      [5,6,7]
     ];
     
data.forEach(d => console.log(d, check(d)));
```

Comment: как то еще можно сделать `(acc,c) => acc.x += (c > acc.m), acc`;

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych поясните, с чего вы вдруг считаете, что ваше видение форматирования кода и числа отступов лучше моего?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych тогда либо ссылку на стандарты оформления кода на SO, либо ерундой не занимайтесь.

Comment: Что-то данный код на все 4 входных массива выдает `false`

Comment: @Yaant накосячил когда первый вариант в стрелочную функцию переписывал